# Aptana Studio 3 content assist is black text on black background(unreadable)

Tags: aptana, content-assist

I have tried to change this by going to preferences-> General-> Appearance-> Colors and Fonts and in the basic folder changes the Content assist foreground color to white and click apply but each time I go back it has changed back to black :(  Anyone know how to fix this? The content assist is unreadable. and yes I have tried restarting aptana and reebooting

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by clicking the theme button and choosing a different theme.

[image: aptana theme menu]

I ran into this problem, and this question came up in a search, so thought I better put an answer up.